# Issue while creating Apex class using API

Tags: apex, rest-api

I'm using REST API to create Apex Class in Salesforce org. It worked in my testing for multiple orgs, but for a customer I'm getting this error -

`Can not create Apex Class on an active organization`.

To create the apex class using API, I'm just creating a object of type `ApexClass` with payload having `name` and `body` of class.

I see that Salesforce doesn't allow creation of classes in a production org directly, but it worked in multiple orgs I tested with, so I think it's allowed to be created by the API.

Is there a org setting that might be preventing this?

Answer (score 6):

You can only create a class in Organizations which are a Sandbox or Developer Edition. For any other type, you will need to *deploy* the class using the `Metadata API`.